# Remove newline from string with robotframework

Tags: robotframework

I need to remove newline from string with robotframework

Here is my string looks like

```
line 1 &
line 2
```

I try to use robotframework keywords `Replace String    ${a}    ${\n}  ${SPACE}`, it doesn't works it my cases, got this error from the log

```
Argument types are:
<type 'unicode'>
<type 'unicode'>
```

It seems `&` unicode char causes this issue, my full string inside the log is `line 1 &\nline 2`
I just want to replace `\n` with space in this cases

Comment: Is that the full error message? Also, I suppose in the actual call you have 2 or more spaces between the args, what is put in the question is just a formatting issue?

Comment: Yes, thats the error message, I can replace string when there is no `&` in my string, still can't figure out how to skip `&`

Comment: It's not the ampersand, it doesn't have anything to do with the issue :) It's how you pass the newline arg.

Comment: Yes i have 2 or more space between the args, i have update the code formatting

Comment: Check the answer below, it's because of the curly brackets which you used for the newline - what was the reason for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to pass the newline character is without the curly brackets:

```
${a}=  Replace String    ${a}    \n    ${SPACE}
Log To Console    ${a}   # prints    line 1 & line 2
```